# Can't figure out how to send ^D (EOT) signal to mailx in bash script

Tags: bash, email, mailx, eot

I'm writing a bash script to send me an email automatically.
Mailx requires an EOT or ^D signal to know the message body is over and it can send.
I don't want to hit ^D on the keyboard when I run script which is what it does now.

Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
SUBJ="Testing"
TO="test@test.com"
MSG="message.txt"

echo "I am emailing you" >> $MSG
echo "Time: `date` " >> $MSG

mail -s "$SUBJ" -q "$MSG" "$TO"

rm -f message.txt
```

Comment: How do you want to tell mailx you finished your body without typing ^D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need to add more text and just need to send the content of $MSG, you can replace

```
mail -s "$SUBJ" -q "$MSG" "$TO"
```

with

```
mail -s "$SUBJ" "$TO" < "$MSG"
```

The `EOT` will be implicit in the `<` construct. `-q` is indeed only used to start a message. The rest is supposed to come through stdin.

Comment: `MSG` is the name of a file, not a string containing the message body. You want `<`, not `<<<`.

Comment: That worked with chepner's '<' use (since i was using a file)! Appreciate it. Both of you.

Comment: @chepner Indeed. I was fooled by the variable name.

Comment: `mail -s "$SUBJ" -q "$MSG" "$TO" < /dev/null` should work as well.

Comment: @user2957985 protip: use `mktemp` to create your temporary filenames to ensure you're not clobbering files that you don't mean to clobber.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output of a command group to `mail`.

```
#! /bin/bash
SUBJ="Testing"
TO="test@test.com"
MSG="message.txt"

{
  echo "I am emailing you"
  echo "Time: `date` "
} | mail -s "$SUBJ" -q "$MGS" "$TO"

rm -f message.txt
```