# What is </dev/null in bash?

Tags: bash

In bash, standard (1) and error (2) output can be  re-routed and discarded with:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

But the following example does something different:

```
nohup myscript.sh >myscript.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
```

What is the meaning/function of `</dev/null` in the example above?  In what sort of scripting scenario would it be useful?

[(Example Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122780/exiting-shell-script-with-background-processes)

Comment: Processes can't be detached if they have any connections to the local TTY. This replaces FD 0, stdin, with a handle on `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`</dev/null` is used to avoid having the script wait for input.

Quoting from [the usage of < /dev/null & in the command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27958/40596):

> `< /dev/null` is used to instantly send EOF to the program, so that it
> doesn't wait for input (`/dev/null`, the null device, is a special
> file that discards all data written to it, but reports that the write
> operation succeeded, and provides no data to any process that reads
> from it, yielding EOF immediately). `&` is a special type of command
> separator used to background the preceding process.

So the command:

```
nohup myscript.sh >myscript.log 2>&1 </dev/null &
#\__/             \___________/ \__/ \________/ ^
# |                    |          |      |      |
# |                    |          |      |  run in background
# |                    |          |      |
# |                    |          |   don't expect input
# |                    |          |   
# |                    |        redirect stderr to stdout
# |                    |           
# |                    redirect stdout to myscript.log
# |
# keep the command running 
# no matter whether the connection is lost or you logout
```

will move to background the command, outputting both stdout and stderr to `myscript.log` without waiting for any input.

Comment: that was a great and helpful. tnx buddy.

Answer (score 56):

Redirecting `/dev/null` to stdin will give an immediate `EOF` to any read call from that process. This is typically useful to detach a process from a tty (such a process is called a daemon). For example, when starting a background process remotely over ssh, you [must redirect stdin](https://serverfault.com/a/36436) to prevent the process waiting for local input.

Another reason to redirect to /dev/null is to prevent an unused file descriptor being created for stdin. This can minimize the total open file handles when you have many long running processes.

Answer (score 5):

`</dev/null` provides empty input to the script...

Answer (score 3):

It is a way to close `stdin`, as if `EOF` (`^D`) were sent to it. It can be used as in this example with  the [`mail` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798650/cant-figure-out-how-to-send-d-eot-signal-to-mailx-in-bash-script/19798799#19798799) to signify it that the command should no more expect input from `stdin`.

It is also often used to daemonize processes (Stop 6 of [the recommended approach for creating well-behaved daemons](http://web.archive.org/web/20120914180018/http://www.steve.org.uk/Reference/Unix/faq_2.html#SEC16))