# keeping a background process running on heroku

Tags: haskell, heroku, rabbitmq, backgroundworker, background-process

I'm trying to run a rabbitmq background process on heroku to pick tasks off a queue and process them. I'm working with the AMQP haskell library and they give the following [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amqp-0.13.0/docs/Network-AMQP.html) (parts omitted or brevity.

```
main = do
    --setup connection omitted
    --connect to queue, wait for messages
    consumeMsgs chan "myQueue" Ack myCallback
    --halts process so messages are taken off the queue until a key is presseed
    getLine -- wait for keypress
    closeConnection conn -- close connection after key
    putStrLn "connection closed"
```

This works fine locally because `getLine` keeps the process running until you press a key. However, when I deploy this to heroku the process exits with

`2016-04-19T08:37:23.373087+00:00 app[worker.1]: worker: <stdin>: hGetChar: end of file`

I figured out from [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955260/what-is-dev-null-in-bash) that this is because in order to deploy a background process via ssh you need to redirect `/dev/null/` to `stdin` which sends an `EOF` signal to the process.

In our case the `getLine` function exits because of this signal and the entire process stops, preventing our worker from staying up.

How can I keep this worker running when I deploy?

**EDIT: Final Solution**
Using @carstons comments I ended up with the following implementation that worked:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    mvar <- newEmptyMVar
    conn <- setupConnection
    queueName <- pack <$> getEnv "QUEUE_NAME"
    chan <- openChannel conn
    consumeMsgs chan queueName Ack processMessage
    installHandler sigINT (Catch (cleanupConnection conn mvar)) Nothing
    putStrLn "Running forever, press ctrl c to exit"
    -- this blocks until sigint is recieved and the handler for SIGINT
    -- "fills" the mvar. once that is filled the process exits
    run <- takeMVar mvar
    case run of
      _ -> return ()

mixpanelConfig :: IO Config
mixpanelConfig = liftM2 Config (ApiToken . pack <$> getEnv "MIXPANEL_API_TOKEN") (newManager tlsManagerSettings)

cleanupConnection :: Connection -> MVar () -> IO ()
cleanupConnection conn mvar = do
  closeConnection conn
  putStrLn "SIGINT received.. closing rabbitmq connection"
  putMVar mvar ()

processMessage :: (Message, Envelope) -> IO ()
```

Comment: if you just want to keep it running *forever* (till killed) you could use `forever $ threadDelay 10000` - if not you should find some way to signal your process to finish - a simple `MVar` should do

Comment: @Carsten thanks for your comment, that did the trick! If you write that as an answer I'll accept it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: the `forever`? - I'll write a short answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I pointed out in the comment if you just want to keep it running forever you can use [`forever`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forever) with - for example - [`threadDelay`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:threadDelay):

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)

main = do
    --setup connection omitted
    --connect to queue, wait for messages
    consumeMsgs chan "myQueue" Ack myCallback
    --halts process so messages are taken off the queue forever
    forever $ threadDelay 10000
    -- so this will never happen and you could remove it
    closeConnection conn -- close connection after key
    putStrLn "connection closed"
```

note that this will of course never really close the connection or exit the application - you'll have to kill the process.

---

the alternative would be a bit more involved as you need some message/way to send your program a termination signal.

An easy way is to use [`MVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html)s which you could set in your `myCallback` when a certain *stop*-message was received on your queue:

```
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

main = do
    -- MVar to receve the quit-signal
    quitSignal <- newEmptyMVar
    --setup connection omitted
    --connect to queue, wait for messages - the callback should
    --set the quitSignal with putMVar quitSignal ()
    consumeMsgs chan "myQueue" Ack (myCallback quitSignal)
    --halts process so messages are taken off the queue till quitSignal
    takeMVar quitSignal
    -- so this will happen after quitSignal was set
    closeConnection conn -- close connection after key
    putStrLn "connection closed"
```