# Exit kubectl command rather than prompt for login

Tags: kubernetes

I'm writing a utility script to retrieve and parse some kubernetes config maps, and typically I'll be authenticated using an oidc token.

In the event when I'm not authenticated, how can I make my `kubectl` command exit with a failure rather than prompt for a username and password?

Here's my current implementation:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Prompts me with "Please enter Username:", and I'd like to exit instead.
kubectl get cm -n my-namespace
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add the output of `k get pod -n kube-system kube-apiserver-master  -o yaml |grep -i auth` , replace it with the name of your master node.

Comment: - --anonymous-auth=false
- --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
- --token-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/tokens/known_tokens.csv
- --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `</dev/null` in your command to [close the std input for the command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955494/6309601). Check the example below, where `kubectl` would print the result normally if things are fine(not prompted), else it will print error text.

Using a known good `kubeconfig` file:

```
kubectl  get pod --kubeconfig good_kube_config </dev/null
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Using a `kubeconfig` with misconfigured username:

```
kubectl  get pod --kubeconfig bad_kube_config </dev/null
Please enter Username: error: EOF
```

You can use something like the below in your script, note that this would print an error on all the failures regardless of their relation with user/pass prompt.

```
if !  kubectl get cm -n my-namespace </dev/null 2>/dev/null;then
      echo "Error: Somthing is wrong!"
      exit 1;
fi
```

If you want to be very specific to user/pass error, then suggest you use a kubectl get command to run a test by greping "Username" string, then proceed.

Note:  To simulate the same prompt, I renamed the user name in my kubeconfig file.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Because I was wanting to pipe the output of my `kubectl` command through `yq`, I've assigned the output of `k get cm` to a variable and tested that for null so I can exit if it's not there; but closing stdin was the bit I was looking for. Thanks again.